# Composite function $g(f(x))$ where $g$ is a power series

Tags: power-series, function-and-relation-composition

Say we have
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\quad\text{for }\vert x\vert<C.
$$
I'm trying to see why
$$
g(f(x))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kf(x)^k\quad\text{for }\vert f(x)\vert<C.
$$
In a sense, sure, it is just a composition of functions, but I am still a bit "worried" about the infinite series. How do we know we can replace all these infinitely many summands by $f(x)$? Could we use the definition perhaps, to ensure nothing goes wrong?;
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k.
$$
I just feel like I'm missing something for this to feel completely safe to me. Any ideas? And please something more than: it's just a composite function, end of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given the series
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\quad\text{for }\vert x\vert<C.
> \end{align*}
>   we can take any $x_0$ with $|x_0|<C$ and **evaluate** $g$ at $x_0$
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x_0)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx_0^k
> \end{align*}
>   Since $|x_0|<C$ the series $g(x_0)$ converges.
>
> Note, that with
>   \begin{align*}
> g(f(x))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kf(x)^k\quad\text{for }\vert f(x)\vert<C.
> \end{align*}
>   we have the same situation, since we consider $g$ **evaluated** at $f(x)$ as we did before with $x_0$. The only aspect we have to assure in order to guarantee the convergence of the series $g(f(x))$ is $|f(x)|<C$. We do not have to consider anything more.

We note that $g\circ f$ is a *composition* of functions. But here we consider the composition of function *evaluated* at a specific point $f(x)$ which is, assuming real valued functions just an ordinary real.

Comment: I see we can evaluate $g(f(x))$ at $x$ for which $\vert f(x)\vert<C$, but are you saying we can only evaluate, and we don't really have a composite function? Because that got me confused.

Comment: @ShaVuklia: Note the difference between $f$ which is a function and $f(x)$ which is a real value, namely $f$ evaluated at $x$. Similarly we *do have* a composition of functions, namely $g\circ f$. But $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$ is the composite $g\circ f$ evaluated at $x$ or in other words, the function $g$ evaluated at $f(x)$.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise we were making  the distinction between $(g\circ f)$ and $(g\circ f)(x)$ here. I usually read those as the same, but in this case I shouldn't.

Comment: @ShaVuklia: Good to see my answer was helpful! :-)

Answer (score 0):

if $|x|<C $ then

$$g (x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_kx^k$$

if $|y|<C $ then
$$g (y)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_ky^k $$

to define $g (z) $, we must have $|z|<C. $

So, to define $g (f (x)) $ you need that
$|f (x)|<C. $
in that case,

$$g (f (x))=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_k (f (x))^k. $$
For example
we can write $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}x^k $ if $|x|<1$

and
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(x^2)^k $$ if $|x^2|<1$.